# How to find out connection between a set of nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a scenario where I know IDs of a list of nodes.
I need to get connection(if exists) between these nodes  given their IDs.
Is there any way to achieve this?
Update:
I am using node id property not the neo4j's internal ID(using like match (n:Person{id:3}))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `IN` clause to select from a list of values:

```
MATCH (n)-[r*..2]-(m)
WHERE ID(n) IN [0,1,2] AND ID(m) IN [2,3,4]
RETURN r
```

I've limited the path length to 2 hops of indeterminate relationship type here, and arbitrarily picked some IDs.

To return the path instead:

```
MATCH p=(n)-[r*..2]-(m)
WHERE ID(n) IN [0,1,2] AND ID(m) IN [2,3,4]
RETURN p
```

Comment: If you have a lot of data, this is an expensive query, can you constrain it by the type of relationship? When you say that the query does not return, are you running in the web console?

Comment: Thank you, it returned when I added labels to m and n in the match statement.

Comment: One more thing, how do I return the complete path instead of just relationship?

Comment: My query is like: MATCH (n:Person)-[r*..5]-(m:Person) WHERE n.id IN [5141,2231] AND m.id IN [3830] RETURN n,r,m;   This does not return all nodes between m and n

Comment: you can try `MATCH completepath=(n:Person)-[r*..5]-(m:Person) WHERE n.id IN [5141,2231] AND m.id IN [3830] RETURN n, m, completepath`. or also just `RETURN n, m, rels(completepath)`, or `nodes(copletepath)`

Answer (score 2):

```
START n=node(1,2,3,4,5,6) //your IDs of a list of nodes
MATCH p=n-[r]-m  //the connection for 1 hop. for multiple hops do n-[r*]-m
WHERE Id(m) in [1,2,3,4,5,6] //your IDs of a list of nodes
RETURN p
```

Comment: Please add an explaination why you think that this solves the problem. Otherwise, it lacks context and is likely to be removed due to “low quality”.

Comment: @lxg Answers that are on-topic and attempts to answer the question don't get removed. Lack of explanation might make it a _poor_ answer, but then you should down vote, not flag for deletion. Flagging should be used for serious concerns like: not an answer at all, question posted as answer, should be a comment not an answer, link-only answer, spam, offensive etc etc.

Comment: @Lundin: The answer was in the “low quality” queue. I voted to not delete it (as it appears to contain something useful), and decided to add a comment instead, so it doesn't get removed by somebody else.